# Is setBounds() called in the EDT?

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, event-dispatch-thread, setbounds

Is the `setBounds()` method of a `Component` like `JPanel` called on the Event Dispatch Thread? I am asking this because I am writing a program that draws platforms and uses a `Swing Timer` to move them up. I override the `setBounds()` method so that every time the `JPanel` is resized, the platforms will resize too. I just want to make sure that `setBounds()` doesn't resize the platforms while the `Timer` is moving them. Also, would it be better to use a `WindowListener` to check if the `JPanel` was resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setBounds() will be called on the EDT by Swing code, but you have to ensure your code's own invocations of setBounds() also only calls it on the EDT. If you can ensure all calls of setBounds() occur on the EDT, then you shouldn't have to worry about setBounds() being executed while your SwingTimer is being executed because SwingTimers also execute on the EDT by default (so they won't execute at the same time).

Also I never seen someone override setBounds() so I do wonder if there's not an alternative solution such as just querying the bounds every time your SwingTimer executes. Using a listener listening for window resizes like you say does sound much better.

Comment: I would check the bounds every time the `Timer` executes, but I stop and start the `Timer` and would like for the platforms to always fit. Thank You!

Comment: I'm just going to use an `AffineTransform` to always make the platforms fit into the `JPanel`.